# Value error in my Oscar Django ecommerce project

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-oscar

[value error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP9H0.png)
[error during template rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7G3k.png)

[Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34qp1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'Basket' instance you are using is not saved on the database. It needs to have a primary key to be used in a relationship with other models, therefore needs to be saved. I do not think there is another way around it.

Comment: if i may ask would assist me if i  share my screen ?

Comment: i understand Django-Oscar assigns automatic pk to each new model instance created..since i;m using foreign key to all my relation models ...seems i don't well how they connect to this pk

Comment: I don't know about Django-Oscar framework, but only the saved instances have pk in Django. Where do you create the Basket model instance in your `views.py`? You may need to save it like so: `your_instance_name.save()`.